# React.js: How to return the previous state value when cancel is clicked in a input field that changes the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-rendering

The parent component passes every prop, state and function, to the child component. Child component has no state or function of its own. Multiple of the same child component are rendered depending on the form fields.

I want a **Cancel** button beside each input field. As it is now, editing the value in the input field also changes the state. Therefore, simply defining the cancelling feature as `handleCancelClick = () => {setEdit(false)}` won't work. Because, it won't revert the changes made to the state. It would let the changed state value appear. Therefore, how do I cancel the edits made and show the original previous value once the **Cancel** is clicked?

Here's the parent:

```
export default function App() {
    const [about, setAbout] = useState("Hi there");
    ...
   
    const handleUserAbout = (about) => {
      console.log(about); };

    const [isEditFields, setIsEditFields] = useState({});

    const handleSetEdit = (name, isEdit) => {
      setIsEditFields((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [name]: isEdit
      }));
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <EditComponent
            fieldName={"About"}
            value={about}
            inputType={"text"}
            placeHolder={"Enter some info"}
            name={"about"}
            onChange={(e) => setAbout(e.target.value)}
            onSubmit={handleUserAbout(about)}
            isEdit={isEditFields.about}
            setEdit={(isEdit) => handleSetEdit("about", isEdit)}
        />
        <EditComponent
            ...
        />
      </div>
    );
}
```

And the child:

```
export default function EditProfileComponent({
  fieldName, value, inputType, placeHolder, name, onChange, onSubmit, isEdit, setEdit }) {
  return (
    <p>
      {fieldName}:{" "}
      {value === "" ? (
        <span>
          <input type={inputType} placeholder={placeHolder} name={name} onChange={onChange} />
          <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Add</button>
        </span>
      ) : !isEdit ? (
        <span>
            {value}<button onClick={() => setEdit(true)}>Edit</button>
        </span>
      ) : (
        <span>
          <input type={inputType} value={value} name={name} onChange={onChange} />
          <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Save</button>
          <button type="submit" onClick={() => setEdit(false)}>Cancel</button>
        </span>
      )}
    </p>
  );
}
```

So, how do I press **Cancel** and have the previous state values reappear over the changed value?

Comment: previous value? or initial value?

Comment: Yes, the initially populated state value.

Comment: you initiated with "Hi There" . do you want to have this on cancel edit?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hook that simple returns your Previous State:

**usePrevious.js**

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export const usePrevious = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
}
```

Then simple call set the Previous state inside your button Handler.

**App.js**

```
//  look here
import {usePrevious} from ".where/ever/you/store/this/usePrevious.js"

const [about, setAbout] = useState("Hi there");
//  look here
const prevValue = usePrevious(about)
const handleCancel = () => {
  console.log(prevValue);
}
return (
      <div className="App">
        <EditComponent
         ...
            onHandleCancel={handleCancel}
        />
        <EditComponent
            ...
        />
      </div>
    );
```

**EditProfileComponent File**

```
...
export default function EditProfileComponent({ onHandleCancel }) {

...

return(
 ...
  <button type="submit" onClick={() => onHandleCancel}>Cancel</button>
 ...
)
...
};
```

**Live Demo**

[image: Edit Get Previous Value]

Comment: How can I trigger this once Cancel is clicked?

Comment: You could pass a handler that listens to changes on your Cancel button. I will edit my answer to this. :)

Comment: @Strange_air I edited so you can take a look if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the previous `state` value in a separate variable. When the user clicks on Cancel Button, retrieve that value from that variable and save it in `state`.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
    const [about, setAbout] = useState("Hi there");
    ...
   
    const handleUserAbout = (about) => {
      console.log(about); };

    const [isEditFields, setIsEditFields] = useState({});
    
    const cancelEdit = () => {
      setAbout("Hi there")
    }
    const handleSetEdit = (name, isEdit) => {
      setIsEditFields((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [name]: isEdit
      }));
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <EditComponent
            fieldName={"About"}
            value={about}
            inputType={"text"}
            placeHolder={"Enter some info"}
            name={"about"}
            onChange={(e) => setAbout(e.target.value)}
            onSubmit={handleUserAbout(about)}
            isEdit={isEditFields.about}
            setEdit={(isEdit) => handleSetEdit("about", isEdit)}
            cancelEdit={cancelEdit}
        />
        <EditComponent
            ...
        />
      </div>
    );
}
```

```
export default function EditProfileComponent({
  fieldName, cancelEdit, value, inputType, placeHolder, name, onChange, onSubmit, isEdit, setEdit }) {

  const handleCancel = () => {
    cancelEdit()
  }

  return (
    <p>
      {fieldName}:{" "}
      {value === "" ? (
        <span>
          <input type={inputType} placeholder={placeHolder} name={name} onChange={onChange} />
          <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Add</button>
        </span>
      ) : !isEdit ? (
        <span>
            {value}<button onClick={() => setEdit(true)}>Edit</button>
        </span>
      ) : (
        <span>
          <input type={inputType} value={value} name={name} onChange={onChange} />
          <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Save</button>
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
        </span>
      )}
    </p>
  );
}
```